# convert the web scraping data to dataframe

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I scrape a data and I tried to convert to json format. However, it seems unsuccessful, I want to convert the dictionary with Keys and Values and then convert to a dataframe.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4
import requests
import json

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6)})
webpage = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8")
webpage = json.loads(webpage)
```

output:

```
{'data': [{'id': 'GILD',
   'attributes': {'longDesc': "Gilead Sciences, Inc., a research-based biopharmaceutical company, discovers, develops, and commercializes medicines in the areas of unmet medical needs in the United States, Europe, and internationally. It was founded in 1987 and is headquartered in Foster City, California.",
    'sectorname': 'Health Care',
    'sectorgics': 35,
    'primaryname': 'Biotechnology',
    'primarygics': 35201010,
    'numberOfEmployees': 11800.0,
    'yearfounded': 1987,
    'streetaddress': '333 Lakeside Drive',
    'streetaddress2': None,
    'streetaddress3': None,
    'streetaddress4': None,
    'city': 'Foster City',
    'peRatioFwd': 9.02045209903122,
    'lastClosePriceEarningsRatio': None,
    'divRate': 2.72,
    'divYield': 4.33,
    'shortIntPctFloat': 1.433,
    'impliedMarketCap': None,
    'marketCap': 78796576654.0,
    'divTimeFrame': 'forward'}}]}
```

I want the result:

df = {'id':'GILD', 'longDesc', 'Gildead...}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, `df` is not a dataframe.

Comment: I have tried to convert the web scraping data to json format by json.loads function. However, it returns a dictionary format but the key value is Data, and all data are the keys.

Comment: In order to meet the guidelines of this site you should demonstrate with code that you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your data you can try this, as part of your code:

```
d = {
    'data': [
        {
            'id': 'GILD',
            'attributes': {
                'longDesc': "Gilead Sciences, Inc., a research-based biopharmaceutical company, discovers, develops, and commercializes medicines in the areas of unmet medical needs in the United States, Europe, and internationally. It was founded in 1987 and is headquartered in Foster City, California.",
                'sectorname': 'Health Care',
                'sectorgics': 35,
                'primaryname': 'Biotechnology',
                'primarygics': 35201010,
                'numberOfEmployees': 11800.0,
                'yearfounded': 1987,
                'streetaddress': '333 Lakeside Drive',
                'streetaddress2': None,
                'streetaddress3': None,
                'streetaddress4': None,
                'city': 'Foster City',
                'peRatioFwd': 9.02045209903122,
                'lastClosePriceEarningsRatio': None,
                'divRate': 2.72,
                'divYield': 4.33,
                'shortIntPctFloat': 1.433,
                'impliedMarketCap': None,
                'marketCap': 78796576654.0,
                'divTimeFrame': 'forward'}
        }
    ]
}

try:
    _id = d['data'][0]['id']
    ld = d['data'][0]['attributes']['longDesc']
    df = {"id": _id, 'longDesc': ld}
except (KeyError, ValueError) as error:
    print(f"Failed to load data: {error}")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 'GILD', 'longDesc': 'Gilead Sciences, Inc., a research-based biopharmaceutical company, discovers, develops, and commercializes medicines in the areas of unmet medical needs in the United States, Europe, and internationally. It was founded in 1987 and is headquartered in Foster City, California.'}
```

**NOTE:** `df` is often referred to as `dataframe`, mostly created with `pandas` module. However, what you have is probably a `JSON` object that gets returned from the request you're making. Having said that, your desired output is actually a `dictionary`, but I kept your naming convention.

EDIT:

To convert your `dict` to a `df` just do this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': 'GILD', 'longDesc': 'Gilead Sciences, Inc., a research-based biopharmaceutical company, discovers, develops, and commercializes medicines in the areas of unmet medical needs in the United States, Europe, and internationally. It was founded in 1987 and is headquartered in Foster City, California.'}
df = pd.Dataframe(d.items())
print(df)
```

This outputs:

```
          0                                                  1
0        id                                               GILD
1  longDesc  Gilead Sciences, Inc., a research-based biopha...
```

Comment: Yes. my goal is to convert that JSON object into a dictionary and then convert to a Pandas DataFrame. I think what I have to do is convert the renamed object into a list and then using APPEND method to create a DataFrame?

Comment: @Janicewww, no you don't have to. It's fine as it is. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Great. It works, thank you for your help. It is very usful.